# In .net is there an easy way to copy files where the source and target could be either file or directory names?

Tags: c#, .net

Basically I want a function where I can provide a string for source that can either be a directory name or a file name and then a target that can also be either a directory name or a file name.  It would need to fail if you attempt to copy a directory to a specific file name, but work in all other cases.  I would also want to be able to pass additional parameters to tell it to overwrite files and/or nuke the target directory prior to copying as well as create the directory if it does not exist.  Anything like that already out there?

Comment: How would you detect that a directory is being copied to a file? All you have is a string... sure if it has an extension it _could be_ a file but not necessarily.

Comment: You have the lego's, snap em together.

Comment: Is the assumption here that the source/target files/directories already exist?  If not, I'm not sure if you can distinguish a file vs directory by its path alone (unless the path ends with a slash, in which case it must be a directory I think)

Comment: @m.Babcock - If it is the source, you can check to see if the file exists with File.Exists() and if not, fall back to see if the directory exists on the file system.

Comment: @asawyer - I could snap it together, and started down that path, but I feel like this must have already been solved.

Comment: Assuming that the paths already exist, you can use System.IO.Directory.Exists and System.IO.File.Exists methods to check the paths and determine if a user is specifying either a directory or path.

Comment: He could make a guess then before performing any actions, ask the user if the guess is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic test I got from a google search...(plus a few modifications)

```
// get the file attributes for file or directory
string someStringFromUserInput = Console.ReadLine();
FileAttributes attr = File.GetAttributes(someStringFromUserInput);

//detect whether its a directory or file
if((attr & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory)
{
    Console.WriteLine("It's a directory");
    //Do some transfer method
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("It's a file");
    //Do some transfer method
}
```

EDIT: This is a very basic example, you'd also want to handle FileNotFoundExceptions for when they try to hit a folder that doesn't exist. But obviously you need to add in your logic to do the copy anyway.

Comment: This works for the source, but for the target, I may want to create a directory if it does not already exist.

Comment: Yeah, you'd want two inputs (source/target) and to check that if the target is a file the source better be a file as well. This was mostly meant to explain the FileAttributes and System.IO methods you'd need to do that sort of a check ;)

Comment: If this is your solution, just make sure to select it as such so other perusing this question will know it was answered. Thx.

Comment: I upvoted it because it halfway answers my question, but I'm more interested in how to solve the other half which is determining from a target string a bunch of things like, is this (or should this be) a directory or file, and in the case of the directory - does it already exist or need to be created?  Really what I was hoping for was an existing dll or snippet of code with the full implementation.  In the meantime, I've continued with my own implementation, but I still feel like something better has to already exist.

Comment: Putting in your existing solution would help a lot. SO is here to help you work through a solution, not as a substitute for your own due diligence.

File Move: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx 

File Functions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc148994.aspx

Pretty much everything you need is in the File class, from what I can tell.